# Wordpress menu (ubermenu) and web page not displaying properly on Apple safari

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, bootstrap-4

I have the following website which I developed a custom wordpress theme for using bootstrap and ubermenu for the menu: http://xtremenutrition.co.za/d-base-staging

Menu alignment looks fine in Chrome, Firefox and internet explorer. Safari on an Apple machine is an issue, where it goes over the logo and if you resize the browser (before the mobile breakpoint), it doesn't look right.

I need help from someone with an Apple and safari computer. Seems I need advice on CSS to recitfy the problem. I'm not sure how to tackle this and what's worse, I have a windows machine only.

Any advice on code/sorting it out would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.